# ReactNative getting started : Screen Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm beginner,

I started a react native project but I don't know how to solve my problem.

Thank you for helping !

[image: step 1]
[image: step 2]
[image: step 3]
[image: Result]
[image: CommonStyle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.
Firstly, in the render method of your HomeScreen class. It should be like this:

```js
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(<MainScreen/>)
    }
}
```

Explanation:
render method always expects a valid JSX element or a function that returns the valid JSX element. This is the reason why Invariant Violation error was thrown, it was expecting a JSX element but instead it got a new object which violates the principal.

Next problem is the syntax error in the render method of your MainScreen class. The closing tag of the button element should not be followed by the bracket. So it should be like this:

```js
export default class MainScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return(
         <Button onPress={()=>{}}></Button>
       ) //correct
    return(
       <Button onPress={()=>{}}> </Button>}
      ) //incorrect
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jsx in your `render` function, don't call `render` from your children

```
render() {
  return <MainView />;
}
```

Comment: It works but now when i click on the button "Go to nice", I have an error : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: I think i did it.